# How to remove completed days from home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

When a habit is marked as `completed`, how can we remove it from the home page so that only uncompleted habits are shown?

**controller**

```
def home
  @habits = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.order(:order)
end
```

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :levels, -> { order(:id) }
    serialize :committed, Array
    before_save :current_level
    attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def completed=(boolean)
      self.completed_at = boolean ? Time.current : nil
    end

    def completed
      completed_at && completed_at >= Time.current.beginning_of_day
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
      today_name = Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
      ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
      where(id: ids)
    end 

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
          def committed_wdays
            committed.map do |day|    
              Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
            end
          end

          def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
              committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.real_missed_days
          end     

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            6
        end
    end

 def real_missed_days
     value = 0
     levels.each do |level|
         value += level.missed_days + level.days_lost
     end
     value
  end

  def calculate_days_lost
      def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
          committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
      end     

   case n_days    
      when 0..9
        n_days
      when 10..24
        n_days-10
      when 25..44
        n_days-25
      when 45..69
        n_days-45
      when 70..99
        n_days-70
      else
        n_days-100
    end
  end

    def days_left_in_current_level
        def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date|
                committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.real_missed_days
        end

        case n_days
          when 0..9
            10-n_days
          when 10..24
            25-n_days
          when 25..44
            45-n_days
          when 45..69
            70-n_days
          when 70..99
            100-n_days
          else
            0 # No end
        end
    end
end
```

I've tried scopes, integrating `completed` into the method `committed_for_today`, and adding additional methods to `@habits` in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a new scope and let's call it `incomplete`:

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :incomplete, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@habits = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.incomplete.order(:order)
```

Comment: I was so close to that answer I'm going to smack myself. I had in the scope `completed: nil`. Thank you!

Comment: No problem ;) it's common to make stupid mistakes every now and then, we are the humans, not machines! :P